# mySQL query; Ignore specific ID values

Tags: mysql

I need to make a mySQL query and am not sure what the format should be.

Here is the situation, I have a table with the fields - id, name, type

I would use a query similar to the following to get results from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type='1'
```

However, I have a list of ID's from another query. These are items that should be excluded from the results.

I'm sure the answer is simple, but I don't know enough about mySQL queries to find the answer.

Comment: Use a `NOT IN()` as:  `WHERE ID NOT IN(1,2,3,4,5,99)`  You can even perform the other query inside it `WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM othertable WHERE othercondition='something')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple NOT IN will be what you want :) It lets you send a list of values and makes sure that its not in them :)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

You could also do it with a subquery with something like:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE type = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NOT IN` query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `type`=1 WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `blocked_ids` FROM `block`);
```

So, you would be having blocked IDs in the `block` table! Hope this helps! :)

Consider this table:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | America     |
|  2 | Europe      |
|  3 | India       |
|  4 | Japan       |
|  5 | Brazil      |
|  6 | Switzerland |
|  7 | Syria       |
|  8 | Wales       |
|  9 | Taiwan      |
| 10 | Zaire       |
+----+-------------+
```

And the blocked table:

```
+-----+
| IDs |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   4 |
|   6 |
|   8 |
|   9 |
+-----+
```

Now, when I give a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `countries` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT * FROM `blocked`);
```

I get this result:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  2 | Europe |
|  3 | India  |
|  5 | Brazil |
|  7 | Syria  |
| 10 | Zaire  |
+----+--------+
```

Hope this helps! :)